# Error in public class

Tags: java

I am attaching the code and the error message, I am not sure what's my mistake here.

BTW I saved the J.java file in the the same directory of javac.
[image: Click to open in new tab]

Comment: The pic is too small, can't read anything. paste your code in the post.

Comment: @lulyon Right click -> Open image in new tab

Comment: Your mistake is putting these two images here instead of a small, readable, searchable text snippet... (Sometimes, one has to think about practicality, even with a nick like that...)

Comment: *Please* include the relevant code in a code block, and console error messages quoted. You're making helping much harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Run the `javac` with `-verbose`.

Comment: @GGrec We shouldn't have to do that though (and if the error is an image, this is completely unsearchable for other people with the same problem).

Comment: No you can just click on the image to open it bigger.

Comment: Code snippet and output as text is more helpful. And maybe follow [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11hello/) tutorial first.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Java PATH variable is set correctly, you have to execute the `javac` command inside the folder containing the class you want to compile. **BUT** the Java artifact must not be in the same folder with the JDK. Move your classes somewhere outside and it will work.

If you don't want to set your PATH variable, just manually point to the `javac` in the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\USER>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\javac J.class
```

Comment: Read the question: _BTW I saved the J.java file in the the same directory of javac_